# my for loop for to update database not woking

Tags: php, session

i have a session array  ie: `$_SESSION['cart_array']`, which contain the following items in it

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => qwerty [quantity] => 1 [unit_price] => 500 ) [1] => Array ( [item_id] => skjbm [quantity] => 1 [unit_price] => 100 ) )
```

and my database inserted item is

```
item_id   unit_price   quantity
qwerty      500          4
skjbm       100          3
```

i want to update this quantity value of their respected item_id with the current session variable and my forloop is

```
$id = $_SESSION['cart_array'];//my current session array items
$ta= count($id);//no of items in session
for($i=0;$i < $ta;$i++){
 $item_id= $id[$i]['item_id'];///got index [] item_id value
 $quantity= $id[$i]['quantity'];///got index [] quantity value
 $qry = ("SELECT * FROM product_added WHERE item_id='$item_id'");  ///Selecting from your products table where the item_id to matche curent item_id

    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
         $qty = $row['quantity']; // Original Quantity value of current item_id
        if ($qty !== $quantity){
            $sql_update=("UPDATE product_added SET quantity='$quantity' WHERE item_id='$item_id' "); 
            echo "updated";

           // If the quantity is not the same as the previous quantity, do something.
         };


    }
```

and my output is

```
updatedupdated
```

but problem is in database it is not updated why ...in which point i m getting wrong do suggest me and rewrite the code thanks in advance...

Comment: print  $sql_update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
    if ($qty !== $quantity){
        $sql_update=("UPDATE product_added SET quantity='$quantity' WHERE item_id='$item_id' "); 
        $result=mysql_query($sql_update);
        if(!$result){
          echo mysql_error();
         }
        else
        echo "updated";

       // If the quantity is not the same as the previous quantity, do something.
     };
```

Comment: thank you @Amar Jain,,,i was mistakenly forgeot the mysql_query()..thank you u made my day....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot `mysql_query()`, so it never performs the update.

`$sql_update=mysql_query("UPDATE product_added SET quantity='$quantity' WHERE item_id='$item_id' ");`

Comment: thank you @Steve Della-Valentina,,,i was mistakenly forgeot the mysql_query()..thank you u made my day....

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_update=("UPDATE product_added SET quantity='$quantity' WHERE item_id='$item_id' "); 
            echo "updated";
```

This isn't a query. You'd actually have to use mysql_query($sql_update);

I'll also add that mysql is deprecated in favour of mysqli.

Comment: thank you @user2784930,,,i was mistakenly forgeot the mysql_query()..thank you u made my day....

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code as follows:

```
$id = $_SESSION['cart_array'];//my current session array items
$ta= count($id);//no of items in session
for($i=0;$i < $ta;$i++){
    $item_id= $id[$i]['item_id'];///got index [] item_id value
    $quantity= $id[$i]['quantity'];///got index [] quantity value
    $qry = ("SELECT * FROM product_added WHERE item_id='$item_id'");  ///Selecting from your products table where the item_id to matche curent item_id

   $result = mysql_query($qry);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   $qty = $row['quantity']; // Original Quantity value of current item_id
    if ($qty !== $quantity){
        $sql_update=("UPDATE product_added SET quantity='$quantity' WHERE item_id='$item_id' "); 

        $sql_query = mysql_query($sql_update);

        if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
           echo "updated"; //update operation succeeded
        }
        else {
          echo 'Updated Failed. Reason : '. mysql_error(); //update operation failed, print the error generated
        }

       // If the quantity is not the same as the previous quantity, do something.
     };
}
```

Comment: thank you @naijaProgrammer,,,i was mistakenly forgeot the mysql_query()..thank you u made my day....